# on scrollup stop jquery function, on scrolldown resume

Tags: jquery, scroll

So i've got an AJAX chat which i'm currently using a setInterval function which isn't very user friendly because it prohibits you from scrolling up.

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ls3rxpuo/

jQuery:

```
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
      $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: 10000 }, 200);
  });
```

Now I want to build upon that script. Q: Stop this function when scrollUp. Resume when Scrolldown. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you read under Q: short for Question there is yes.

Comment: well. its more of a procedure on how the desired script i'm looking for is suppose to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen when user are scrolling up.

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
$('#yourDiv').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

    var evt = window.event || e //equalize event object     
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt; //convert to originalEvent if possible               
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta //check for detail first, because it is used by Opera and FF

    if(delta > 0) {
        //scroll up
        clearInterval(interval); // stop your interval 
    }else{
        //scroll down
    }   
});
```

Comment: works partly., However, when i scroll down and new messages arrive it wont keep scrolling down (script not resumed?) Thanks for your effort!

Comment: after when you stop your interval, and you stop scrolling up, you need to run again your code